# Lost column name when applying lm with summarise/across

Tags: r, dplyr, lm, broom

I want to use `summarise`/`across` with `lm` to fit regressions using different columns in a tibble.  Like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

fits <- tibble(mtcars) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(vs, am), ~list(tidy(lm(wt ~ .x + mpg)))))
```

But the columns that get passed into `lm` as `'.x'`, end up labeled as `.x` in the regression output.

```r
fits %>% unnest(vs)

# A tibble: 3 x 6
  term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value am              
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <list>          
1 (Intercept)   6.10      0.353     17.3   8.36e-17 <tibble [3 × 5]>
2 .x            0.0738    0.239      0.308 7.60e- 1 <tibble [3 × 5]>
3 mpg          -0.145     0.0200    -7.24  5.63e- 8 <tibble [3 × 5]>
```

I can preserve the name if I build the `lm` formula on the fly, and use `cur_column()`, but this feels kludgy:

```r
tibble(mtcars) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(vs, am), 
           ~list(tidy(lm(formula(paste0("wt ~ ", cur_column(), " + mpg"))))))) %>% 
  unnest(vs)

# A tibble: 3 x 6
  term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value am              
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <list>          
1 (Intercept)   6.10      0.353     17.3   8.36e-17 <tibble [3 × 5]>
2 vs            0.0738    0.239      0.308 7.60e- 1 <tibble [3 × 5]>
3 mpg          -0.145     0.0200    -7.24  5.63e- 8 <tibble [3 × 5]>
```

I want the output to correctly use the true column name of `.x`, without having to do this workaround, but still using the `summarise`/`across` motif, **without incorporating `map`**.

Seems like this should be possible.  Any suggestions?

*copying my comment from @akrun's answer to clarify what i'm looking for:

> What I really want to know is, is the column name preserved in the summarise/across operation in a way that I can reference it directly in lm. Something like {{.x}} or rlang::as_name(.x). I mean, I know those don't work, but it seems like name information should be preserved, aside from just the string version in cur_column.

Comment: I don't understand. Which part of the answer that you already have do you wish to change?

Comment: @RonakShah I copied my comment from akrun's post, I hope that explains a bit more what I'm looking for.  But then again, if both you and akrun don't see an obvious way to do what I want to do, it may just be that it isn't actually available in the `dplyr` approach I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

Can make it shorter with `reformulate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)
tibble(mtcars) %>%
   summarise(across(c(vs, am), ~       
     list(tidy(lm(reformulate(c(cur_column(), "mpg"), "wt")))))) %>% 
   unnest(vs)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
#  term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value am              
#  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <list>          
#1 (Intercept)   6.10      0.353     17.3   8.36e-17 <tibble [3 × 5]>
#2 vs            0.0738    0.239      0.308 7.60e- 1 <tibble [3 × 5]>
#3 mpg          -0.145     0.0200    -7.24  5.63e- 8 <tibble [3 × 5]>
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun.  It's true, it's a little cleaner that way.  What I really want to know is, is the column name preserved in the `summarise`/`across` operation in a way that I can reference it directly in `lm`.  Something like `{{.x}}` or `rlang::as_name(.x)`.  I mean, I know those don't work, but it seems like name information should be preserved, aside from just the string version in `cur_column`. At least that seems like a reasonable thing to expect, to me!